# How to display a MKMapView without street names?

Tags: ios, geolocation, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to display a map without street names. is it possible using  MKMapView ? if not, is there a different map API for iOs that supports this?

thanks,
Nimrod

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do, is to set the maptype to Satellite.

Here's how to do this:

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
```

EDIT:
Not sure if it's satellite, but try one of these:

```
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
```

Comment: yes, thats an option, but I prefer a classic map view, not satellite.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you will have to browse the API if you don't want the satellite map.

Comment: If your stuck in the middle of stellite and classic use Hybrid!!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Nimrod, you can't show the map view hiding the street name, only showing the Satellite view. However, check the [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) - they just launched it and they provide a lot of thinks that the default MKMapView don't provide.

Answer (score 0):

The [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mobile) will allow you to customize your map completely, including removing street names, but with MapKit-like functionality.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer, you can use the Google Maps SDK and make a custom map in this link:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter
And then use the atributes generated in this to custom your map in the app.